# Google billing Internal Test : Test Card not showing

Tags: android, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription, android-billing, google-play-billing

I have my app in the internal testing track but when Testing, the test card did not show up and it asked for the real credit card on both real and virtual devices.

I have tried some method recommended by StaclkOverFlow such as removing all GG account and clear Google Play data then add only one tester account but I have got no luck.

Could you please give me some reasons why test card did not show up???

This is the picture when testing:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My mistake is not adding License Tester.
After adding, clear Play Store Data and re-login by License Tester account, test card showed.

[image]

Comment: I hesitated to "Clear Data" and just cleared the cache but it still didn't work, so yes, clearing data is essential despite the warning you might get from the OS.

Thanks!

Comment: Not working for me, cleared cache, for Google Play Services and Google Play Store, still in app suggests to add payment method, instead of showing test cards.

Answer (score 5):

Just had the same problem. Eventually it will show up, but to speed up the process, go to "Google Play" app's settings and in Storage, tap "Clear data" (not only cache).
Then test cards will show up immediately upon re-launching your app.

Answer (score 3):

I spent 2 days on it until I found out that after adding license testers I also needed to check the checkbox next to the added list in Setup -> License testing.

[image: Image showing what I mean]

The checked checkbox on the testing track page is not enough.

Comment: I spent 3 days .... it was the same thing ... thank you !!! geeez !

Answer (score 1):

Clearing play store data in app info resolves my problem.